# Is there a way to know if any program is listening to my microphone. Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, privacy

I recently used my PC to make a VOIP call. I thought I hung up but 2 hours later I realized the call was on.

I'm  concerned about the wider privacy implications.
My webcam in contrast has a light indication that the camera is on.

I know that I can disable/enable permission for different programs in Win 10, but I *did* allow this program and still didn't notice it's listening/recording.

I'm asking if there is a simple way know if any program is using the mic, note that there may more then one, (for example the built in one, usb mic, usb webcam).

If there is a programmatic approach, that would be welcome as well.

Comment: When an application is running which has access to your microphone, Windows 10 (1909+) at least, there is a taskbar icon that indicates that is the case.  So what version of Windows 10 are you using exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound, You're right, and I didn't realize that there is a builtin functionality in Win10.

Comment: Slightly glib but wholly sincere recommendation from an infosec devops dinosaur: Physically isconnect your microphone when you're not using it.

Comment: @Shadur, good point. Do you have any suggestion for built in laptop mic?

Comment: A hammer and/or a soldering iron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is a simple way know if any program is using the mic?

Hover your cursor over the microphone in your system tray.

> **How to See What’s Using Your Microphone Right Now**
>
> If an application is using your microphone, you’ll see a microphone
> icon in your notification area, also known as your system tray. It’s
> black if you’re using Windows 10’s light theme and white if you’re
> using Windows 10’s dark theme.
>
> Hover your cursor over the icon and Windows will tell you which app is
> currently using your microphone. If more than one application is
> currently using your microphone, Windows will show you how many
> applications are using your microphone.

...

> If you don’t see the microphone icon, be sure to check the overflow
> menu by clicking the up arrow to the left of your notification icons.
> If the microphone icon is hidden here and you’d prefer it visible on
> your taskbar, you can drag and drop it to the notification area on
> your taskbar.

...

> This icon only appears while an application is currently using, or listening to, your microphone. If you don’t see it, no applications are using your microphone right now.

Source: [How to See Which Apps Are Using Your Microphone on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/424153/how-to-see-which-apps-are-using-your-microphone-on-windows-10/)

See the link above if you need to see example screenshots.