# Is the mic listening when my Windows PC is LOCKED, any indicator?

Tags: windows-10, microphone, privacy

I use my PC to make a VOIP calls. The call does not disconnect when PC locks.

From this answer, https://superuser.com/a/1563833/1191544,  I realized that there is an indication in the notification area when mic is used.
**But no indication shows the mic is listening when the PC is locked**.

I'm concerned about the wider privacy implications.
My webcam in contrast has a light indication that the camera is on.

I know that I can disable/enable permission for different programs in Windows 10, but think of a case when the PC is listening/recording and then locks automatically. *The microphone might by recording, and you wouldn't notice.*

I'm asking if there is a simple way know if any program is using the mic while locked, note that there may more then one, (for example: the built in mic, usb mic, usb webcam, *Bluetooth earpiece*).

Some windows applications do show a control or indication even when locked e.g. Groove music. This is obviously not a Windows feature but a choice of the application developer.

If there is a programmatic approach to add an indicator or disconnect the the mic, that would be welcome as well.

**Edit:**
As suggested in comment, I tested this:
I tried with my VOIP client MicroSIP: placed a phone call, then locked PC, sure enough the conversation carried on even when locked.

Comment: I think if you could it would defeat the purpose of the lock screen.

Comment: Quick test. Install Audacity and start recording. Make some noise so you know it's recording and shows on-screen. Lock the machine, sing a song or something, unlock the PC and see if your rendition of the song was recorded.

Comment: @spikey_richie, I tried with my VOIP client MicroSIP, sure enough the conversation carried on even when locked.

Comment: @Moab, possibly. Although there are some applications that have indicators even when locked, e.g. Groovy music.

Comment: Hardware hack: get an external microphone with a hardware switch. Then disable the built-in microphone and uninstall the drivers. I guess that's the only 100% sure solution. A less-intrusive way is to plug in a loose cable into the existing microphone jack or buy a cheap usb-audio adapter which can be easily plugged in or unplugged. Windows will automatically use the new device as 'default', overriding the built-in mic (but some programs could still opt for using another mic or even scan all the installed mics).

Comment: Programmatic approach: See the section "How to Deactivate Microphone Using Registry Editor" on: https://www.maketecheasier.com/deactivate-microphone-windows10/
I'm sure there's a programmatic way to write a registry variable, and then either automate the task or run the scripts when appropriate.